# Mouser over row in one table to change the style of another row of another table

Tags: html, css

How do I get to change the style of the rows of one table when passing the mouse over the rows of a different table whose elements are related to each other?

Here is the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mah2uou2/4/) of What I am trying to do.

Sample code:

```css
table#table1 #el1:hover + table#table2 tr.el1 {
  background: #000 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}
#table1 tr:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- table 1 -->
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="table1">
  <tr id="el1">
    <td>Element1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="el2">
    <td>Element2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="el3">
    <td>Element3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- table 2 -->
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table2">
  <tr class="el1">
    <td>ReferenceElement1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="el3">
    <td>REferenceElement3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="el2">
    <td>ReferenceElement2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="el3">
    <td>REferenceElement3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want a CSS only solution.

Notice that I wanted to do a `:hover` on the `tr` element whose `id` is `#el1` in the first `table` and change the style on the second `table` where the elements are rows with the `.el1 class`

Comment: That is not possible using CSS alone.

Comment: A man can implement a Turing complete system in CSS and I can simply make a mouse over effect? C'mon! http://eli.fox-epste.in/rule110/

Comment: Nope.. CSS hover cannot affect other elements that are not children or siblings. in this case they are neither. You need Javascript.

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida doesn't matters. You can achieve a lot of amazing things with CSS, but your HTML markup needs to be perfect. In your case it's impossible, because with CSS you can't go back to the parents to select another element that is not a children or a sibling, as Paulie_D said.

Comment: @Eduardo CSS is not Turing complete. HTML+CSS is (http://lemire.me/blog/2011/03/08/breaking-news-htmlcss-is-turing-complete/)

Comment: you can change the background color of other table's tr on hover of one table tr but for related to row with their similar child..work is going on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with CSS alone
But only a little jQuery script will make you day

http://jsfiddle.net/tL1ap7w4/

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.table-trigger tr')
    .on('mouseenter', function() {
      console.log(this);

     $('.'+$(this).attr('id'), '.table-trigger-target')
        .addClass('hover')
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
        $('.'+$(this).attr('id'), '.table-trigger-target')
          .removeClass('hover')
    })
});
```

```css
table#tabela1 tr:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#tabela1 tr:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table-trigger-target tr.hover{
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-trigger" id="tabela1">
  <tr id="el1">
    <td>Elemento1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="el2">
    <td>Elemento2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="el3">
    <td>Elemento3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered table-trigger-target" id="tabela2">
  <tr class="el1">
    <td>ReferenciaElemento1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="el3">
    <td>REferenciaElemento3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="el2">
    <td>ReferenciaElemento2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="el3">
    <td>REferenciaElemento3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you!!! Man, I can't believe this is not possible only with CSS. I am really upset!!! Thank you again!